# git stash pop/apply to specific index include previous index

Tags: git

Suppose that i have stash history as follow:

```
stash@{0}: WIP on dev:
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 
stash@{2}: WIP on dev:
stash@{3}: WIP on master:
```

I want to have scenario as follow:

1. Git apply/pop to stash@{3} 0 will include stash@{0}, stash@{1}, stash@{2} and stash@{3} (eg: git pop stash@{3} --history
2. Git apply/pop all (eg: git pop --all)
3. Git apply/pop all on specific branch stash (eg: pop 0 and 3 only for master branch) (eg: git pop --all --master)

I know i can do it one by one like git stash pop x 4 times or git stash specific index serveral times but it is tedious. Is there any command as above???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in command to apply the scenarios you describe in one single command.

You can write your own scripts :

all 3 scenarios you describe can :

- use `grep` and `head` on the output of `git stash list` to select the stash(es) to apply
- apply the given stashes

Beware the indexes in `stash@{xx}` : each time you use `git stash pop stash@{xx}`, all the indexes after `xx` get shifted.

You could also only use `git stash apply stash@{xx}`, and run `git stash drop stash@{xx}` at the end, once again, beware the indexes : you should probably drop the stashes in reverse order.